# How can I check a range of an array contains zeros?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an integer array like {1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,5,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,1}

I want to check if the array's 5th element to 9th element is all 0's.

following code i tried...

```
if (Enumerable.Range(vHisto[i],vHisto[ i + 30]).Contains(0))
{
    x = i+30;
    break;
}
```

vHisto is a list which contain some integers to check like example.

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your code snippet.

Comment: It's difficult to see the problem if we don't know what language it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always Linq.  Always.

```
var sixThroughTenAreZero = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,3}
                                    .Skip(5)
                                    .Take(5)
                                    .All(x => x == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert integer array to string and then using substring.

```
 int[] arr = {0,1,2,3,0,1};
 string results = string.Join("",arr.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());

 if(results.Substring(4,9).equals("00000"))
{

}
```